# Which JAR was loaded by which dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, dependencies

I have many dependencies which loaded a lot of jars into my project.
How can I check which jar was loaded by which dependency?

There is this jar file:

```
M2_REPO\commons-io\commons-io\1.3.2.v20080604-1500_orbit\commons-io-1.3.2.v20080604-1500_orbit.jar
```

As you can see, the version of my `Apache Commons IO` is 1.3.2. The latest version, which I need, is 2.4. When I just add the latest JAR file into my project and add this

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
```

it doesn't seem to recognize it as it doesn't recognize some of the new features of the latest version. So I need to delete the corresponding dependency.
Or is it possible to just exclude the old file from the dependencies without changing anything else?
PS: I looked for the keyword "commons" in my pom.xml but didn't find anything related to this.

Comment: You need to add it as a dependency in pom file.

Comment: Add the dependency you need in your own pom.xml.  A newer version will override the old one specified by commons-io.

Comment: You can use the dependency:tree target to display the hierarchy of which Maven sub-projects correspond to which declared dependencies. See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html

Answer (score 1):

The following maven command should tell you from which jar you are getting commons-io:commons-io.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=commons-io:commons-io
```

Once you know, from which jar you are transitively pulling the jar you may exclude the commons-io jar.